# color 'blobs' in normal map - how to fix them?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, texture-baking, mirror, normal-map

[image]My normal map I created from a high poly mesh to a retopologized low poly mesh is showing some errors. There are places at the ears, some at the neck, head; everywhere where there are high resolution details or the mirror edge, it shows color errors like in the image below (green dots on the normal map or in general really weird color blobs).
 Is there a way to manipulate the color/influence the settings so that this does not happen? Both models got slight differences in their form, apart from that their topology is completely different. 
I'd be happy for any help.
[image: normal map fractals]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is an option to reduce such artifacts. How? *Using a cage*. The cage is a duplicate mesh of the original mesh that you then set up to raycast for the normal mapping. An alternative way is to color pick the pixels close to where it looks fine and just gently move/paint them in place so the deformation disappears. I didn't know that back then. Cages are also really fragile beings. **Don't apply any modifiers to cages**. Leave them be. Otherwise you will get mosaic-like deformations. To fix those, you'd need to use a new copy of the target mesh and set it to fit the broken cage with an **unapplied** shrinkwrap modifier. 
Hope this helps!